# Return arrays from foreach and sum their values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, sum

In a category overview, I need to sum all items that were studied in all the subcategories.

I have a function countitemsinsubcat() inside a foreach() that returns an array '$value' for each subcategory ($id_cat).

```
foreach ($subcategory as $row) {
    $value =& countitemsinsubcat($id_cat);

    $all_values_found [] = $value; 
}
```

So these is $all_values_found for a category that has 2 subcategories:

```
Array (
   [0] => Array(
     [Istudied] => 0
     [Itotal] => 1
    )

[1] => Array (
    [Istudied] => 1
    [Itotal] => 4
    )
)
```

In a category overview, I want to sum the values of the arrays of each subcategory, and get a 'total' array, like this:

```
Array
(
            [Istudied] => 1
            [Itotal] => 5
)
```

Any suggestions on how do this?

Comment: have you tried something or just want from to do your work?

Comment: you may find array_reduce to be helpful here

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code snippet [PHP]:

```
//The magic happens here:

function concatit($v, $w)
{
    $v[Istudied] += $w[Istudied];
    $v[Itotal] += $w[Itotal];
    return $v;
}

//Declaring the array.

$a = array (array(
        Istudied => 0,
        Itotal => 1
    ),array (
        Istudied => 1,
        Itotal => 4
    )
);

//Making a call to the 'concatit' function declared above from within array_reduce.

$d = array_reduce($a, "concatit");

//Now $d contains the array as you wanted it.

echo $d[Istudied].' '.$d[Itotal];
```

Let me know if you need further clarifications! Enjoy!